# php+Laravleの環境構築からプロジェクト作成

Tags: php, laravel

サイトを参考に、php+Laravelのプロジェクトを作成したのですが、下記の表示は正常にプロジェクトが作成されている証でしょうか？
teratailさんで以前に同様な質問をさせて頂いた際に古いので違うと言われたのですが、検索してみてもこの表示が正解のように出ているので分からないです。

・参考サイト
https://qiita.com/H-Toshi/items/144fa458abe9b8e4b22b

・以前、質問をしたサイト
https://teratail.com/questions/je7gwq9rzbfbsc

現在はこちらが表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

こちらの表示は正しくプロジェクトを作成されているのでしょうか？
正しいか教えて頂けると幸いです。